# Install Spark 1.5 in existing Hortonworks HDP Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm new to Hadoop and want find the way how to install Spark 1.5.1 on the existing Hadoop cluster. 4 nodes, Ubuntu 14.04. Hadoop 2.3.2. Ambari Version 2.1.2.1. Followed [tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/apache-spark-1-5-1-technical-preview-with-hdp-2-3/), but there are spark version for the Ubuntu 12, and I cannot install it on our system. So after step 1 I stucked. `sudo apt-get install spark_2_3_2_1_12-master -y`
Got an error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package spark_2_3_2_1_12-master

Can anyone provide us with some guidline, how to install 1.5?
Currently we have Spark 1.4 installed, up, and running, but due to requirement of functionality need the 1.5!

Comment: FYI, Ambari is not a cluster, it is a management and monitoring tool that Hortonworks HDP utilizes.

Comment: Yes I know, was on rush when was writing this post. Any more usefull comments ? And is it possible at all ? Anyone ?!

Comment: I cannot believe that no one knows anything about it ... Any ideas people ? It is still an issue, and I can't find the solution ...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr is not officially supported by HDP. If you look at the repos available for stack updates, [HDP stack public repos](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_hdp_stack_repositories.html), they only have ones up for Centos, Red Hat, and Oracle Linux. Did you try using Spark's Simple Build Tool to build spark-1.5 source against your Hadoop install ? You would need to set SPARK_HADOOP_HOME=your hadoop location. See this for [step by step with Ubuntu 14.04 and an earlier version of Spark](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/). I don't see why the same steps would fail with Spark 1.5.